# How to convert from var to string

Tags: scheme

I try to do something like that:

```
assume x=

(define foo 5)
```

I need to do:

```
(string-append "a" "b" (cadr  x))
```

(when x no knowing..)

How can I convert the var (cadr  x) to string or there is other sulotion?

Thanks

Comment: Notice that you must not use `cadr` for accessing the value of a variable, `cadr` is used for accessing the second element in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting a number to a string use the [`number->string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._number-%7E3estring%29%29) procedure:

```
(number->string 5)
=> "5"
```

And for converting a symbol to a string use the [`symbol->string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._symbol-%7E3estring%29%29) procedure:

```
(symbol->string 'x)
=> "x"
```

Some examples, pick the one that better reflects your needs - because it's not clear at all what you intended to ask in the question:

```
(define foo 5)
(string-append "a" "b" (number->string foo))
=> "ab5"

(define x '(1 5))
(string-append "a" "b" (number->string (cadr x)))
=> "ab5"

(define x '(define foo 5))
(string-append "a" "b" (number->string (caddr x)))
=> "ab5"

(define x '(define foo 5))
(string-append "a" "b" (symbol->string (cadr x)))
=> "abfoo"
```